Who is this person and why am I being attacked?
I have answered several questions on this site. I have given no medical advice except to "see a doctor now" if I thought it necessary. Yet here are a few comments from a comment thread I had today(on a cartoon character!) (on Biology, but the commenter specifically mentioned cogsci):

-Thou shalt not advertise thy work in medicine lest someone judge thine post as advice –  caseyr547 10 hours ago
  ---- @caseyr547 - There are many people who can be exposed to patients, including doctors, nurses, nurses' aides, etc. I deny any label given me. –  anongoodnurse 23 mins ago
  - actually you would be liable because you label yourself nurse and so could be sued for practicing. –  caseyr547 14 mins ago
  ---- @caseyr547 - I haven't labeled myself a nurse! I said a lot of different people can "see" patients in the ER. And I have prescribed nothing. Cut me a break. Anon, good nurse! is a line from Romeo and Juliette. and who would follow the advice of a non-good nurse? –  anongoodnurse 10 mins ago
  - @anongoodnurse you're splitting hairs one which will cost you your license or job and if you give bad advice here or on cogsci (especially about those particularly ill) i will see to it that it will. –  caseyr547 8 mins ago
  ---- @caseyr547 - Bullshit. Are you a jealous person? Do you actually think you can come after me and destroy me for advice I give on the internet when I so carefully: 1) give good advice and 2) Qualify it and refer to experts? Who are you, anyway, to be so petty? –  anongoodnurse 4 mins ago
  - @anongoodnurse jealous no. zealous yes. i dont care what you think your doing its malpractice. –  caseyr547 2 mins ago 

What's the problem here? Is there something I don't know about the answers I'm giving on this site? If there is, I'd appreciate hearing from a mod. 
I don't want to be attacked or threatened in comments after I do my best to supply decent answers.
Is this a one off, or is this a site wide sentiment? In no case have I prescribed a course of action that wasn't pro seeing a therapist or doctor when warranted.

This person is suspended on Cognitive Science. Without looking into this issue on Biology I can't judge about this particular instance.
He is most likely referring to Cognitive Science's rules of not allowing to explicitly prescribe treatments in answers.
This user has a history of raising unnecessary discussion in comments. Flags should be used for this purpose, which are evaluated by the moderators of the site. Adding noise like this in comments is not fruitful. As Josh mentioned, flag any comments you find offensive or problematic for moderator attention, and the Biology mods will take care of it.

Thank you very much, that is quite a relief.
